# Small objects: create frequently or reuse?

Tags: c#, object

For example, in draw method I need an instance of Rectangle to be used. Like this:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(FrameSize * CurrentFrame, 0, FrameSize, FrameSize);
```

Or other way. Define temp rectangle data member, and then use it like this:

```
rect.X = FrameSize * CurrentFrame;
rect.Y = 0;
rect.Width = FrameSize;
rect.Height = FrameSize;
```

Which way is better? One thing confuses me is that many rectangles created frequently, but many code solutions use first approach, while second one should be careful about memory consumptions.

Comment: The cost of a Rectangle instantiation is vanishingly small unless you are doing a LOT of them every draw call, I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have proved by careful measurement that reuse improves your performance you should create a new object every time.

.NET handles object creation and GC very efficient, you should not worry about any performance hit here. The second solution needs more careful coding to make sure you don't reuse objects in use somewhere else and you don't have previous state lugging around. Further more you will have more objects aging into gen1 or gen2 in the GC.

Comment: I generally create temp instances in method and reuse them within this method only.

Comment: Measure Measure Measure.

Answer (score 3):

I would personally use the first approach in most cases - ideally making the type immutable if it makes sense and if the type is under your control.

The garbage collector is very good at reclaiming short-lived objects - and creating new objects means you don't need to worry about whether *something* still has a reference to the old object (thus making changes to it a problem).

Answer (score 2):

How long lived are the objects?  If they're only created locally and then used by the drawing methods, then chances are they will get collected in generation zero which is fairly efficient.

The problem with re-using a temp rectangle is that if you try to let it hang around beyond the life of a method it will be problematic for modifications in general.

As a general rule, I'd go with #1, and ONLY consider #2 if you discover later after profiling that #1 became an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The former is safer when it comes to possible bugs, in respect to Rectangle class being mutable can produce some weird and hard to spot effects.

I don't think the performance penalty is serious enough to risk venturing in the wild world of mutable structs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the fact that structs are allocated on stack, in case of drawing method I personally would choose the first approach, as

1. Object created and initialized
2. Used
3. Pushed to GC  as we leave the function.

So this is small object which is fast created and fast removed from the memory.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it on an instance basis. You're not gaining much by reusing it, and it makes your code easier to break. By doing it on an instance basis, you can encapsulate some logic in a method and you won't have to worry about it breaking due to factors outside of the method.